# Predicate logic rectified form

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have this predicate logic expression

$$\forall X (\forall X p(X) \vee q(X))$$

Which of these expressions are the rectified form?

$$ \forall Y (\forall X p(X) \vee q(Y)) $$

$$ \forall X( \forall Y p(Y) \vee q(Y)) $$

I have been told that the rectified form of a predicate can be obtained by renaming bound variables so that no variable appears in two quantifiers.
According to that in my opinion the answer should be the first one but using software I get the second one.

Comment: Different tools may define the scope of quantifiers differently.  If the scope of the inner quantifier is the entire expression in the outermost parentheses, you get the second "rectified" expression.  I'm not saying this is the explanation, but it's worth a check.

Comment: I have check with more parentheses, like this $$\forall X (\forall X (p(X)) \vee q(X))$$ and I get the same results. ¿It is the first one really a rectified form?

Comment: @Emon If the precedence was different you'd need $\forall X((\forall Xp(X))\lor q(X))$, not what you wrote which is identical to what you had before.

Comment: I have just checked that and it is neither correct. If I supose that the scope is like this $$\forall X((\forall Xp(X))\lor q(X))$$ which one is the correct?

Comment: For $\forall X((\forall X p(X)) \vee q(X))$ you should get $\forall X ((\forall Y p(Y)) \vee q(X))$ with any reasonable tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am with you. The first one is equivalent to the original, but in the second one the $Y$ in $q(Y)$ has become a free variable and the $\forall X$ is a null quantifier, while the original expression did not have any free variables or null quantifiers.  Are you sure the software did not say $\forall X (\forall Y p(Y) \lor q(X))$? What software is this?

Comment: It's quite possible that the precedence is different. If $\forall X(\forall Xp(X)\lor q(X))$ means $\forall X(\forall X(p(X)\lor q(X)))$ then the answer the software gave makes complete sense.

Comment: The software I have used is https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/ . I have also tried \forall X (\forall Y p(Y) \lor q(X)) but it says it is not equivalent. The input for the software is $$(\forall X (\forall X p(X) \vee q(X)))\leftrightarrow(\forall X (\forall Y p(Y) \lor q(X)))$$ that must be valid if they are equivalent.

Comment: @Emon I tried it myself, and it says it *is* valid ... Oh!!! I may see what's going on: did you really use capitol letters X and Y for the variables?  Because those are used for predicates!  For variables you need to use lower case letters x and y.